# With EC secp256k1 is there a way of transforming a function of the private key to a function of the public key?

Tags: elliptic-curves

A key pair has a private key $D_A$ and a public key $Q_A$.

$D_A$ is an integer less than the curve's $n$.

Is there any (boolean) function of the private key $f(D_A)$ which can be transformed into a function of the public key $f'(Q_A)$?

i.e. are there any relationships between private keys which can be calculated knowing only the public keys?

Comment: Not really… unless someone really messes things up in code or usage. Instead of some function, it’s mostly “a human factor” allowing key recovery. As with most things in crypto – if you don’t beware of known pitfalls, things might quickly become less random and less secure than expected; with known consequences. Eg: [Recovering private key when someone uses the same k twice in ECDSA signatures](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/35848/6218), or [Recovering Bitcoin private keys using weak signatures from the blockchain](https://nilsschneider.net/2013/01/28/recovering-bitcoin-private-keys.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secp256k1 is a curve, not a scheme - you can build different schemes over it that have different private/public key relationships.

If you do plain ElGamal on secp256k1 for example, $Q_A = D_A . P$ for a public base point $P$ so you get the usual key-sharing properties: if my keypair is $(D_A, Q_A)$ and yours is $(D_B, Q_B)$ then anyone can compute $Q = Q_A + Q_B$ to produce a public key whose secret key is $D = D_A + D_B$. If they can encrypt a message under $Q$, you and me have to cooperate to decrypt it as the secret key is effectively $2:2$ secret-shared.

In summary: if the function mapping secret to public keys is linear (which it often is) then one can transform linear relationships in the way you asked for.

Comment: Does this also apply to ECDSA?

Comment: ECDSA is a bit more complicated (for one thing, it's a signature not an encryption scheme, but mainly because you need both $k$ and $1/k$ for a secret $k$) but threshold signatures do exist: https://freedom-to-tinker.com/blog/stevenag/threshold-signatures-for-bitcoin-wallets-are-finally-here/

Answer (score 2):

We aren't aware of any sich relations. In fact, one assumes that the group of elliptic curve points behave like a [Generic Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_group_model).
A generic group is a group, where the encoding of the elements are chosen as a random values.